# How can I set the wallpaper programaticly?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, wallpaper

I want to set the wallpaper on phone boot.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest add this permission:

```
<uses -permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Later in your code:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);

Bitmap wallpaper = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
```

Comment: or add an image from sdcard ?

Comment: in Activity, Service or Broadcast Receivers, you can use it

Comment: you have to use context.getResources() instead of getResources()

Comment: and instead of 'this', use context\

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to set the wallpaper.
Remember to put the wallpaper image in the res/raw directory.(You can add this manually if it hasn't been made yet)

```
public void setWall(){

InputStream wall = getResources().openRawResource(wallpaper);

Bitmap back = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wall);

try {

getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(back);

}

catch(IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}}
```

and ofcourse set the permission in the manifest with this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

This will set the wallpaper to your phone and will stay after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

use `scheduler` of `android` mostly `crontab`

write a script to pick wallpaper from a location

on a condition like change in date

schedule this script into the `scheduler` at a particular time

so it will run at that time of day and will do your job

Comment: I think the question was to set the wallpaper at **Boot**  time.... However information regarding crontab may be helpful in some cases....thanks for that!!!